# ODBC Linked server in sql 2005 doesn’t work from remote box

Tags: sql-server-2005, odbc, linked-server, clarion

I have a dev workstation with sql 2005 installed and in it I created a linked server to a odbc connection to a clarion database. I can run select statements against it inside sql Mgt studio. When I take a second workstation and connect to the sql on the first box using sql mgt studio, then try the exact same query I get

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "liveclarion" returned message "[SoftVelocity Inc.][TopSpeed ODBC Driver][ISAM]ISAM Table Not Found".

Any thoughts? It appears to have the same functionality on a second sql server. No remote sql mgt studio connect success in queries against my linked ODBC clarion DB.

All done with windows authentication and the same AD user.

Answer (score 0):

The error returned by the ODBC driver is "SAM table not found".

So I'm assuming you have a table called SAM - presumably in a table called Sam.Tps?

I'm wondering if you need to set a path to that file - ie if there's some difference in path or file name validity between your two tests. One assumes not, but I'd look in that direction first.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I don't think you understand.  This works fine when I connect using sql mgt studio on the box that has the sql instance running on it.  But when I use a second box and run sql mgt studio to connect to the box that has the DB, it doesn't work.  It is the same DB just connecting from a remote box using sql mgt studio.  Also It is ISAM not SAM.  ISAM stands for Indexed Sequential Access Method.

Comment: oh gosh, yeah, I missed the I. 
I get that it works on the server, but not a remote. 
I've not done this before, but I'm wondering if the ISAM file is handled by the server, or by the Sql Mgmt Studio. 
On the server box, can you run a query, using the ISAM table from a program _other_ than Sql Mgmt Studio?